# Verify a (Metamask) transaction has happened on NodeJS

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

What is the best way to verify a (Metamask) transaction has happened on NodeJS?

Use case:

A user buys a digital card with ether. After the user buys the digital card, a route on the server runs some code, makes a PDF, etc..

What is the recommended way to have a server (ExpressJS) verify that a tx has happened and is successful?

I was thinking of two options, but I'm pretty new to Ethereum so I'm probably missing some details here.

Have the server listen to events from the contract. When an event comes in, it'll have the user's address and prove they paid. Then I can make the card.
The only thing that I'm concerned here with is that maybe some details of the card are private. And if it's in the logs, it'll be public.

or..

OR have the user sign the message locally, push it to the server and somehow send it to the contract. I'm not sure what the details are with this route.
Are there any recommended ways to accomplish something like this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I could understand the problem properly, but I will try to give some help.

In the first case the logs will not have any private information unless you write it in a event, return it or store it in a public variable. Your main concern should be how you send the information to the contract, if it is not somehow encrypted it could be a problem. That said I would prefer the second solution.

Also, you can await for the transaction logs and check if it is succeeded or also make it asynchronously.

```
const receipt = await contract.methods.yourFunction().send({ from: address });
```

```
contract.methods
            .yourFunction()
            .send({ from: address })
            .then(receipt => {
                // Do something with your receipt
            });
```

Comment: Tip: If you're not sure about the Question, you can comment asking for clarification.

Comment: I know how to submit a tx to Ethereum, the question is how can I verify a tx has happened on a server.